# How to place through solder pads of different shapes in EAGLE?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I searched everywhere and watched many eagle tutorials, but I couldn't find out how to place circle and square through hole solder pads.

In the Eagle parts list, I only found the octagon solder pad. I would really like to know how to place pads of different shapes, square, circle...

[image: Octagon solder pad]

I've started learning Eagle yesterday, and I have managed to put together a 3PDT daughter board schematic and design a PCB:

[image: 3PDT Schematic]
[image: 3PDT Board]

Any help is very appreciated :)

Comment: I haven't used Eagle, but in Altium and KiCAD, you place pad stacks while building a component, and can choose pad shapes there.  You are apparently placing pre-made components that consist of a single solder pad - you would have to edit those components to change the pad shape, pad size or hole size.

Comment: @PeterBennett: Yes, that's how Eagle works, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Bennett described in his comment, you're looking at pre-made single pads in a library. You're limited to the choices that the person who developed the library made at the time.

If you create a custom component of your own in the library editor, you have the full range of pad shapes and sizes available to you.

Comment: Is there a library I can download that contains already made pads ?

Comment: You could spend time searching for such a library, or you could simply learn how to use the library editor. It really isn't all that hard.

Comment: @galaxyworks:  If you do any amount of electronic design work, you WILL have to make your own schematic components and PCB footprints, so you may as well start learning now.  When using Altium,I usually found it much quicker to make my own parts than to search the libraries for what I wanted.

Comment: You are right! I'll start learning making my own components. 
Thank you both very much :)